# python recursive function give false if the number is not at the center of list passed, hope to get some inputs

Tags: python, binary-search

The logic works if i add return in the else and elseif conditions. The parameters of the function is a sorted list, number to be searched, start index and end index of the list.

```
def binary_search_recursive(data, inpNum, low, high):

    mid = (low + high) // 2

    if low == high:
        return inpNum == data[mid]

    if inpNum == data[mid]:
        return True

    elif inpNum < data[mid]:
        binary_search_recursive(data, inpNum, low, mid - 1)

    else:
        binary_search_recursive(data, inpNum, mid + 1, high)

    return False
```

Comment: So, what exactly is the question?

Comment: May be you need and extra stop condition, like `if low > high: return False`

Comment: Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: sorry i had the wrong code in the question. If the above code is executed with a sorted number list and the number to be searched is not in the middle of the list, it will always return false. I just wanted to understand the cause for that.

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff low > high state will not be reached as the low == high condition will be the final condition in the iteration

Comment: @DILIPKUMAR what if low=3, hi=4, then mid = 3. if (inpNum < data[3]) then you will search with low=3, hi=2... not so good. May be that not solve your problem... but i think your stop condition is not strong enough

Comment: thanks for the inputs everyone , i think i got the answer to my initial question. The else if should have a return as the value is returned back to the parent calling the fucntion, it was very silly question :)

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff thanks appreciate your suggestion :)